# Trying to run jitsi/web image on EKS but facing the "failed to pull and unpack image" issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, amazon-eks, jitsi

[image: Error]

Althouth the jitsi/web image is a public image and I was able to run nginx image I was expecting to run the jitsi/web image similarly but faced the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `latest` tag for `jitsi/web`.

You can use `stable` tag.

[image]